# Refactoring JUnit tests to extend over multiple methods and test cases

Tags: java, junit, enums

As a personal exercise in algorithms and unit testing, I am implementing different sorting algorithms in a `Sort` class and testing them with JUnit Jupiter.
The idea is to set up a few test cases, then test each of the implementations against them.

**The Problem:** is that I am struggling to write the test class in such a way that it:

1. Uniformly tests a sorting algorithm against all of the test cases even if we come back and add *more test cases* in the future, and
2. Uniformly tests all sorting algorithms in the `Sort` class even if we come back and add *more algorithms* in the future.

---

**Attempts**

**[1]** Before I started worrying about any of those extensions, I first set everything up manually:

```
// Sort class
public class Sort {
    public static int[] insertionSort (int[] array) { ... }
    public static int[] selectionSort (int[] array) { ... }
}

// JUnit
class SortTest {
    private static int[] expectedCase1;
    private static int[] expectedCase2;
    private int[] testCase1;
    private int[] testCase2;

    @BeforeAll static void setExpectedArrays () {
        // Initialise expected results
        expectedCase1 = new int[]{1};
        ...
    }
    @BeforeEach void setTestArrays () {
        // Initialise/reset test arrays
    }

    @Test void insertionSortCase1 () {
        assertArrayEquals(
            expectedCase1,
            Sort.insertionSort(testCase1)
        );
    }
    @Test void insertionSortCase2 () { ... }

    @Test void selectionSortCase1 () { ... }
    @Test void selectionSortCase2 () { ... }

}
```

But this manual approach quickly grows tedious as I move on to implement more sorting algorithms and testing cases. None of it is automatic and there's a high chance that I will make copy-and-paste errors that silently invalidate the test results (e.g. still calling `Sort.selectionSort(testCase1);` on a new `@Test void mergeSortCase1 ()`.

**[2]** Then I learned about [@ParameterizedTest](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests)s and tried encapsulating test cases in an enum:

```
// Inside the test class:
private enum ArrayCase {
    SINGLETON(
        new int[]{2},   // expected array
        new int[]{2}    // test array
    ),
    REVERSE_SORTED(
        new int[]{-1,3,6,7,9},
        new int[]{9,7,6,3,-1}
    ),
    ...
    private final int[] sortedArray;
    private final int[] testArray;
    // Constructor
    ArrayCase (int[] sortedArray, int[] testArray) {
        this.sortedArray = sortedArray;
        this.testArray   = testArray;
    }
    // Accessor
    public int[] expectedArray () { ... }
    public int[] testArray     () { ... }
}
```

Then the actual tests got reduced to:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@EnumSource(ArrayCase.class)
void insertionSort (ArrayCase arrayCase) {
    assertArrayEquals(
        arrayCase.expectedArray(),
        Sort.insertionSort(arrayCase.testArray())
    );
}
```

And I can also add new cases by adding another element to the enum so we don't have to touch the actual testing code:

```
MOSTLY_DUPLICATES(
    new int[]{-1,-1,0,0,0,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,7,7,7,9,9},
    new int[]{4,9,4,-1,9,0,2,2,2,7,-1,0,3,4,7,0,7}
),
...
```

I still have to write one `@ParameterizedTest` for each method in the `Sort` class, but it becomes a lot more manageable.

**Sub-problem:** However, as I went on to convert the tests for selection sort into this idiom, I found out that its test arrays were already sorted from the previous parameterised test for insertion sort since they all share the same arrays in the enum behind the scene.
I couldn't incorporate the `@BeforeAll` or `@BeforeEach` in this kind of structure so I would like to know how best to solve this. Furthermore, there's still the question of enumerating the sorting algorithms automatically as well.

As much as I like to solve this sub-problem, I am also open to an entirely different approach as long as we can address the main problem I outlined at the beginning of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest to create an interface for the sorting logic:

```
public interface ISortingAlgorithm {
  int[] sort(int[] input);
}
```

Then, each of your sorting algorithm is a class implementing this interface.

Afterwards, I would create a parameterized, abstract test class, which holds different test cases (which are not specific for an implementation of a sorting algorithm).

```
public abstract class AbstractSortingTest {

  private ISortingAlgorithm algorithm;

  @BeforeAll
  public void setUp() {
    this.algorithm = createAlgorithm();
  }

  protected abstract ISortingAlgorithm createAlgorithm();

  @ParameterizedTest
  @ValueSource(...)
  public void testSorting1(int[] input, int[] expectedResult) {
    assertEquals(expectedResult, this.algorithm.sort(input));
  }
}
```

Then, you can create a sub class for each algorithm in which you just need to create an instance of the algorithm.
(Probably, you don't even need the abstract class and can parameterize the used implementation as well.)

```
public class InsertionSortTest extends AbstractSortingTest {

  @Override
  protected ISortingAlgorithm createAlgorithm() {
    return new InsertionSort();
  }
}
```

**Regarding your sub-problem:**
Depending on your implementation, you might be modifying the original input array. I suggest to use System.arraycopy() to create a copy of the array such that you don't modify the original one.

Comment: **Sub-problem:** Thanks! I got it to work by having the test array accessor return a clone of the array.  **Main problem:** [A] How would you supply the test cases and feed them through the @ValueSource in this example? [B] Can you clarify on what you meant by ".. parameterize the used implementation.."? Do you mean we can also feed different sorting algorithms into the test as another parameter as well? And finally (slightly unrelated) [C] What design choices should one consider when choosing between several implementations in a single class vs several children of an interface?

Comment: [A] Sorry, I guess that `@ValueSource` is not working in this case. `@EnumSource` or `@MethodSource` should be working (https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-parameterized-tests/#Method-Source) [B] That would be theoretically possible, but I personally would prefer the proposed solution using test class inheritance. [C] I would never put different implementations of the same specification into one class. See also: strategy pattern

Comment: Wow, the strategy pattern is quite clear and helped me understand your answer a lot better now. I'll switch to it and then revisit the JUnit-related problems. As I was looking into it, I also came across dynamic test and test factory. Do you think they will be a more suitable option in this case?